# Notation for "A does not imply B"

Tags: notation

I'm looking for a way to express *A being true does not imply B*. I know that *A implies B* can be written as $A \rightarrow B$, but what about *A does not imply B*? $A \not\rightarrow B$?

Comment: Simply write $A\land\neg B$, though that is probably not what you are after. I think you want something like "$p$ is prime does not imply in general that $p$ is odd", right?

Comment: May be this link help you ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Comment: @BabakSorouh That tells me how to write the symbol in LaTeX, but not what the symbol means (except possibly by its name).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, it's the latter I'm after.

Comment: I just came here to learn to write $can \nRightarrow should$

Comment: So that's how you write not-arrow in MathJax!

Comment: My answer is here: [Not necessarily imply](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4252038/21813)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use a generic $\to$ or $\Rightarrow$ for *imply* then slash through for the *not-imply*.

But you can perhaps do better. If you actually mean syntactic entailment (so non-implication is a matter of there being no proof from $A$ to $B$ in the relevant proof system) then $A \nvdash B$ is available and absolutely standard.

If you actually mean semantic entailment (so non-implication is a matter of there being a valuation which makes $A$ true without making $B$ true) then $A \nvDash B$ is available and quite standard.

Comment: Is there a way to formulate $A \nvdash B$ with just and's, or's, and not's?

Answer (score 8):

Usually, we use double arrows for implications: $A\Rightarrow B$.  You can use a crossed out double arrow for does not imply: $A\nRightarrow B$.  In LaTeX, these are "\Rightarrow" and "\nRightarrow", respectively.

Comment: I would usually see single arrow $A \rightarrow B$ and negation $A \nrightarrow B$.

Comment: These are both used. In logic texts, for instance, the object language's notion of implication (i.e., propositional calculus or predicate calculus, etc) is often denoted by $A \to B$, whereas in the meta language (i.e., statements *about* the object language) the double arrow $A \implies B$ is used. Both are valid but shouldn't be used interchangeably.

Comment: In my opinion, $\implies$ (literally `\implies` in LaTeX) is preferable for communicating logical implication, as $\rightarrow$ is often used to denote functional mappings, etc.